# Gradient gap between content and footer

Tags: css, wordpress, gradient

Okay, so I have been working on this website and I'm trying to convert it into a wordpress theme. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this the gradient seems to work on longer pages on this site. http://codykrauskopf.com/performers.html and then on this site http://codykrauskopf.com/?page_id=4  the gradient doesn't go all the way down to the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `style.css` change `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you put the before on the wrong element.

Change the css rule to:

```
#content:before {
content: '';
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
//rest of your css is ok
}
```

Comment: The reason it's on the wrap is because I need the content in the content pane to not have the gradient applied to it. Bodzio's answer seems to have fixed it.